# Thinking process behind checking if a function is linear or not

Tags: linear-algebra

So I was making an exercise out of "Introduction to Applied Linear Algebra" ~Stephen Boyd. It's the following one.

Linear or not? Determine whether each of the following scalar-valued functions of $n$-
vectors is linear. If it is a linear function, give its inner product representation, i.e., an
$n$-vector a for which $f(x) = a T x$ for all $x$. If it is not linear, give specific $x$, $y$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$
for which superposition fails, i.e.,

$f(\alpha x + \beta y) \ne \alpha f(x) + \beta f(y)$.

(a) The spread of values of the vector, defined as $f(x) = \max_k x_k − \min_k x_k$.

(b) The difference of the last element and the first, $f(x) = x_n − x_1$.

(c) The median of an $n$-vector, where we will assume $n = 2k + 1$ is odd. The median of
the vector $x$ is defined as the $(k + 1)$-st largest number among the entries of $x$. For
example, the median of $(−7.1, 3.2, −1.5)$ is $−1.5$.

(d) The average of the entries with odd indices, minus the average of the entries with
even indices. You can assume that $n = 2k$ is even.

(e) Vector extrapolation, defined as $x_n + (x_n − x_{n−1})$, for $n \ge 2$. (This is a simple
prediction of what $x_{n+1}$ would be, based on a straight line drawn through $x_n$ and
$x_{n−1}$.)

I know that to determine if a function is linear or not I should start looking if the superposition doesn't fail.
I don't really understand where to start with exercises like this and what's the thinking process behind it. Do I start from trying to find an inner product vector?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, learn to use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You just said it. Check the superpositions.

Comment: I see, but how would I go from for example $f(x)=x_n−x_1$ to $f(αx+βy)≠αf(x)+βf(y)$ to check if the superposition is valid or not?

Comment: Is it right if I do the additivity test like this? $f(x + y) = (x + y)_n - (x + y)_1 = (x_n - x_1) + (y_n - y_1)$ Then I can fill in values for x and y for example $x = (0, 1)$ and $y = (1, 0)$ if I fill these in, the additivity test succeeds. Do x and y always need to be opposites to perform these tests though?

Comment: Try some simple examples. If it doesn't seem like you can find a counterexample to show the function is not linear, then try to prove the function is linear.

Comment: So I should just try some inputs to see if I can find counterexamples? Shouldn't there be a more practical way to solve an exercise like this?

Comment: Trying simple examples is super practical and you should do it all the time whenever you're doing math.